# Algebra question involving function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I solve the following problem

suppose $h(x)=\sqrt{6x-3}$

find two functions f and g such that $(f\cdot g)(x)=h(x)$

How would I solve it do I need to find two functions that mutltiply to $h(x)$.

Comment: Just to make sure: does the problem ask for $(f \circ g)$ or $(f * g)$? The former is $f(g(x))$ and the latter is $f(x) \cdot g(x)$.

Comment: When you write $(f*g)(x)$, you mean simply the pointwise product $f(x)g(x)$, right? Not a [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)?

Comment: No I meant sorry what george posted first with the little circle not the star

Comment: Let $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=h(x)$. (No, don't do this...)

Comment: It is vulgar to use an asterisk for ordinary multiplication in TeX or MathJax or the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean **multiplication of functions**, then

Let $f(x)g(x) = f^2(x) = \sqrt{6x - 3} = h(x).$ Then $f(x) = (6x - 3)^{\large\frac 14}$.

Then $$f(x)\cdot g(x) = f^2(x) = \left((6x - 3)^{\large\frac 14}\right)^2 = (6x - 3)^{\large\frac 12} = \sqrt{6x - 3} = h(x)$$

**If you mean Function composition:**

How about $g(x) = 6x$ and $f(x) = \sqrt{x - 3}$.

Then $$(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x)) = f(6x) = \sqrt{6x-3} = h(x)$$

Comment: yes that makes because you plug in 6x into x of the f(x) function.

Comment: Exactly right, Fernando!

Comment: Does that make sense? Function composition is often written $fg(x) = (f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x)) = h(x)$, so I'm assuming that's what you meant. If you mean you need to find $f$ and $g$ such that $f(x) \cdot g(x) = h(x)$, then the top portion applies: multiplication, or a product, of functions.

Comment: yes it make sense.

Answer (score 1):

#### If you mean function composition:

$$(f \circ g)(x) = \sqrt{6x-3}$$

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and $g(x) = 6x - 3$. Then $f(g(x)) = \sqrt{6x-3}$.

Or you could use $g(x) = x$ and then simply $f(x) = \sqrt{6x-3}$. This answer is completely valid, if not a little fresh.

There are actually infinitely many solutions, so I assume you want one. In the event you get a multiple choice question asking for a possible solution, just plug in $g(x)$ as $x$ in $f(x)$ and see which one gives $h(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $(f*g)(x)=h(x)$  is the same notation as $fg(x)$ or $$f(g (x))$$

So I will say $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and $g(x) = 6x-3$ because

$$f(g (x)) = f(6x-3) = \sqrt{6x-3}$$